# Why is some output from system() missing when I debug program with qemu & chroot

Tags: qemu, chroot

Recently, I tried to debug a cross compiled arm program with QEMU, but I got stuck with an issue.

This is the code, very simple.

```
int main()  
{  
    printf("aaa\n");
    int  status;  
    status = system("./bin/ls"); 
    printf("Result of [system] = 0x%x\n", status);
}
```

When I launch the program using command

```
spy@spy-virtual-machine:/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf$ ./qemu-arm-static -L ./ ./a.out
```

The output is:

```
aaa
bin              include          lib              test.c           qemu-arm-static  a.out            qemu-arm         shell.sh
Result of [system] = 0x0
```

But when I launch the program with chroot like this:

```
spy@spy-virtual-machine:/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf$ sudo chroot ./ ./qemu-arm-static -L ./ ./a.out
```

The output turns out to be:

```
aaa
Result of [system] = 0x7f00
```

Apparently the `system("./bin/ls")` is not run as expected.

But the `./bin/ls` command can be run by chroot & QEMU:

```
spy@spy-virtual-machine:/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf$ sudo chroot ./ ./qemu-arm-static -L ./ ./bin/ls
bin              include          lib              test.c           qemu-arm-static  a.out            qemu-arm         shell.sh
```

Now I'm totally confused. Can anybody give me a hint on this, and what can I do to get the right output of `system` function when using `chroot` command.

All command line input and output can be found in this picture:
[Command line content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSZ84.png)

Answer (score 1):

From [man 3 system](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system):

> system() executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c
> command

So you need a working shell inside the chroot in order to be able to successfully invoke system().

The following happens when this program runs in qemu-arm-static: `system()` results in `fork()` followed by `exec()` for the shell. When you run it without chroot this is your host (x86) shell. The shell then calls `fork()` followed by `exec()` for the `bin/ls` (ARM). My understanding is that it can only succeed if you have binfmt handler for the ARM ELF registered on your host. In that case registered qemu-arm gets loaded and it executes `bin/ls`.

When you do the same thing in the chroot the host shell is not accessible, so `system()` results in `exec()` call for the `bin/sh` (ARM). It looks like your binfmt handler is not accessible inside the chroot, and because of that loading `bin/sh` fails and error status is returned from `system()`.

You can check registered binfmt handlers in the /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc

Comment: We already have a shell in the ```bin``` directory inside the chroot.  I can launch ```bin/sh``` from qemu, but my program still fails to run ```system```.   [Command line output is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOnMr.png)